Prompting for all inputs at beginning of sequential tasks
I have created a tasks.json file for my project, which I'm using to both build and flash my project onto hardware. There is a "build" task, a "flash" task and a "build + flash" task, which just sequentially runs the other two.
The user is prompted to select the build profile (used by both tasks) and the flash method (used by "flash" task only).
My issue being that the flash method is prompted only after the "build" task has successfully completed. I would much prefer if all required user inputs were prompted at the beginning.
I have achieved that by adding a dummy option to the "build" task, which uses the flash method input variable, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution than this. Is there maybe some setting I am missing?
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".venv/bin/python",
            "args": [
                "script/build.py",
                "build",
                "--profile", "${input:buildProfile}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "options": {"env": {"dummy": "${input:interface}"}}, // dummy option, so flashing interface is prompted at beginning
        },
        {
            "label": "flash",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".venv/bin/python",
            "args": [
                "script/build.py",
                "flash",
                "--profile", "${input:buildProfile}",
                "--interface", "${input:interface}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "build + flash",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "build",
                "flash"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "buildProfile",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                "debug",
                "develop",
                "release"
            ],
            "default": "develop",
            "description": "Select the build profile"
        },
        {
            "id": "interface",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                "stlink",
                "jlink"
            ],
            "default": "stlink",
            "description": "Select the flashing interface"
        }
    ]
}


with the extension I wrote: Command Variable you can ask multiple stuff and put it in a remember store and later get a key-value pair when you need the value, combine with transform and use multiple pickStringRemember variables with empty property, and use remember to retrieve a key

if you raise a feature-request, please add a link here to your ticket.
